# Express res.redirect to https broken

Tags: angular, express, https

I've read quite a few of the posts with the same title. I have tried the suggestions that were given, non has worked

I want to automatically redirect in production - if it's not secured.
This is an angular2 app, server api.

This is the first middle ware in the express app.js

```
// HTTPS
app.use (function (req, res, next) { 
    if ( req.secure || req.headers.host === 'localhost:3002' ) {
        next();
    } else { 
        res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
```

The message I'm getting from FF is this

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

I do not have cookies disabled. and I make no protocol reference in angular, so I don't know why it would be balking on the redirect. Where can I look? What can I try?

Comment: Do you have this redirect code in your https server?  It should not be there, only in your http server.

Comment: @jfriend - I only have one server.

Comment: How can you have only one server?  You have to have a different server for http and https because they're on different ports and one is listening for https.  Your https server should NOT be doing the redirect.  That's probably the issue here because it creates an infinite redirect loop which is likely what the browser detects.  If you're sharing code between the two servers, then you need to make sure you are NOT redirecting when the protocol is already https.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Express encapsulates some header parsing and I needed to include

app.enable('trust proxy');

excellent article - https://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/redirecting-http-to-https-with-nodejs.html